# Open a file from the command line

Tags: kile

The default kile version (Kile 2.9.91) shipped with kubuntu 18.04 does not behave as expected. In older versions this

```
$ kile myfile.tex
```

would open `myfile.tex` for editing. However, in the current version this tries and fails to open `http://myfile.tex`. The error message I get is "http://myfile.tex Host not found", which is not too surprising. I tried to wrap the filename in quotes, use `kile ./myfile.tex` and `kile file://myfile.tex`. The first did not change anything, the second and third resulted in a segfault.

What is the right way to open files using the command line in Kile 2.9.91?

### What works, what doesn't?

```
$ kile myfile.tex                         -> Error: http://myfile.tex
$ kile "myfile.tex"                       -> Error: http://myfile.tex
$ kile myfile.txt                         -> Error: http://myfile.txt
$ kile myfile                             -> Error: http://myfile
$ kile Documents/myfile.tex               -> Error: http://documents/myfile.tex

$ kile ~/Documents/myfile.tex             -> Works!
$ kile /home/user/Documents/myfile.tex    -> Works!
$ kile $(realpath myfile.tex)             -> Works!

$ kile ./myfile.tex                       -> segfault
$ kile file://myfile.tex                  -> segfault
```

Comment: I don't use Kile but in Kubuntu 18.04, the version should be 2.9.91. Where did you get Kile 3 from?

Comment: Oh, valid point, I only get a Kile 3 beta 1 banner / splash screen, the version is the one you say. I updated the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue if I call `kile myfile.tex` on clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. But if I have `myfile.tex` in `~/Documents` and open it with `kile ~/Documents/myfile.tex` it opens normally. On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS it does not need full file path.

Comment: Does this also happen with different file extensions (e.g. .txt) or no file extension at all (e.g. `kile myfile`)?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I added a table with all combinations that came to mind (and a dirty hacky workaround).

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I am quite disgusted that the developers let such a blunder occur.

Comment: Added info and link to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kile/+bug/1800355

Answer (score 2):

Dirty workaround time: write a function into your `.bashrc`/ `.zshrc` (others might work these two are the only ones I tested) that calls `realpath` to get the absolute path of the input file:

```
function kile-open {
    kile $(realpath $1)
}
```

To regain the intended behavior (for one file at a time, not working with any other parameters, this can easily be improved with some bash knowledge). This is by no means a solution, just a way to mimic the intended behavior for now.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @m00am solution, in `bash` you can add the following to the `.bashrc`:

```
kile() { command kile $(realpath "$@") }
```

The command `kile myfile.tex` will then work. Personnally, I even redirect the output to `/dev/null` and release the command:

```
kile() { command kile $(realpath "$@") > /dev/null 2>&1 & }
```

Comment: Very nice! Better than my hack, since I cannot 'forget' to use it.